# MongoDB calculate date between 2 fields in document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection that each document have 2 fields of dates (start date/ end date)
And I want to return documents that the diff between the end date and the start date its in the least 30 minutes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation with a single [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage and use [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to calculate difference between 2 dates :

```
var dateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date
}, { collection: "dates" });

var DateModel = db.model('DateModel', dateSchema);

DateModel.aggregate({
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: { $gte: [{ $subtract: ["$endDate", "$startDate"] }, 30 * 60 * 1000] },
            then: "$$KEEP",
            else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
})
```